# Error when trying to run npm build on gitlab-ci with terraform

Tags: amazon-s3, gitlab, terraform, gitlab-ci, amazon-cloudfront

I'm new to terraform but I've been fairly successful so far. I'm trying to get a mithril app to be built and deployed fully with terraform and gitlab to aws s3 and cloudfront. It is failing on this block here:

```
 data "external" "frontend_build" {
  program = ["bash", "-c",
    <<EOT
(npm ci && npm run build -- --env.PARAM="$(jq -r '.param')") >&2 && echo "{\"dest\": \"dist\"}"
EOT 
  ]
  working_dir = "${path.module}/frontend"
  query = {
    param = "Hi from Terraform!"
  }
}
```

Here is the error message from gitlab:

```
Error: External Program Lookup Failed
│ 
│   with data.external.frontend_build,
│   on data.tf line 2, in data "external" "frontend_build":
│    2:   program = ["bash", "-c", <<EOT
│    3: (npm ci && npm run build -- --env.PARAM="$(jq -r '.param')") >&2 && echo "{\"dest\": \"dist\"}"
│    4: EOT
│    5:   ]
│ 
│ The data source received an unexpected error while attempting to find the
│ program.
│ 
│ The program must be accessible according to the platform where Terraform is
│ running.
│ 
│ If the expected program should be automatically found on the platform where
│ Terraform is running, ensure that the program is in an expected directory.
│ On Unix-based platforms, these directories are typically searched based on
│ the '$PATH' environment variable. On Windows-based platforms, these
│ directories are typically searched based on the '%PATH%' environment
│ variable.
│ 
│ If the expected program is relative to the Terraform configuration, it is
│ recommended that the program name includes the interpolated value of
│ 'path.module' before the program name to ensure that it is compatible with
│ varying module usage. For example: "${path.module}/my-program"
│ 
│ The program must also be executable according to the platform where
│ Terraform is running. On Unix-based platforms, the file on the filesystem
│ must have the executable bit set. On Windows-based platforms, no action is
│ typically necessary.
│ 
│ Platform: linux
│ Program: bash
│ Error: exec: "bash": executable file not found in $PATH
```

I got this code from a tutorial so it may be outdated, but I can't find anyone else talking about this particular thing.

EDIT:
Here is my .gitlab-ci.yml

```yaml
include:
  - template: Terraform.latest.gitlab-ci.yml

variables:
  TF_STATE_NAME: default
  TF_CACHE_KEY: default
  TF_ROOT: terraform/
```

Comment: Which OS are you using in the pipeline, Ubuntu, something else?

Comment: We need to see the GitlabCI config especially the agent vonfiguration. You may also want to remove the `query` block if you are not using it for anything.

Comment: I added the yml to the post and removed the query block from my code. As for the OS I think it's ubuntu but I'm not sure how to check.